# Converting character(13-Dec-2012) to date in R

Tags: r, date, character

I am working on a dataset. Variable date has the character type data in this format"13-Dec-2012".
I need to convert this character into date format.
I tried some ways but couldn't figure it out. 
Any help is appreciated.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `lubridate` package. `dmy` means `day-month-year`.

```
library(lubridate)

dmy("13-Dec-2012")
# [1] "2012-12-13"
```

Or use the base R. See this link to learn more about the format of date specification (https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html).

```
as.Date("13-Dec-2012", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
# [1] "2012-12-13"
```

Or use the `anydate` function from the `anytime` package.

```
library(anytime)

anydate("13-Dec-2012")
# [1] "2012-12-13"
```